# Mimic nth-letter with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

CSS (currently) does not have any sort of `nth-letter` psuedo-selector. Is there a way to mimic this selector with jQuery, without using a bunch of `span` tags?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, that's not possible without a dozen of wrappers.

Comment: Comment because the solution is a bit complex and your question is a bit broad. Basically, depending on your requirements, you'd need to modify jquery to add the selector `nth-letter` and select based off of the parent selector. Then, after getting the dom element text nodes (`text()`), you could count the characters (or letters) and split the string to add a span around the element with inline styles or a specifically styled class.

Comment: @KevinPeno That's what I've done below, minus the nth-letter selector bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your letter is wrap in a tag of sort (span, em, div, or whichever...), it is not a DOM element. So you can not in effect target it directly with CSS or DOM-manipulation functions.

Comment: The letter isn't, but everything is within a dom element, which is a string, which can be manipulated. You would not need to wrap the letter before using JavaScript to apply it (as the OP requested).

Comment: @Kevin The string can, but as I said, the letter cannot be *directly* targeted. Hence, you cannot create a jquery pseudo selector for it. You'd have to select the text node, split the string and wrap the letter in an different node to style it differently.

Comment: @Kevin: Retrieved, yes.  Removed?  Inserted?  With a bit of work.  But you can't style or animate a text node.  And you especially can't style *part* of a text node.

Comment: @Damp I'm unsure how I'm wrong here. You can create a jQuery selector for anything. You cannot use the underlying method of `querySelectorAll` for the entire operation, however. You'd need to implement on top of it.

@cHao that doesn't make this answer less wrong. I never said that you *could* style a letter within a text node directly :)

Comment: @Kevin a selector helps you retrieve DOM element(s) (actually, a jquery wrapped DOM element or list of DOM elements). You can write a selector to possibly retrieve the whole text node, but not the individual letter. If you did, you would end up with a string and not a reference to a DOM element...

Comment: @Kevin:  Well, considering a jQuery object is effectively a list of elements, and a string is not an element, what would this selector return?

Comment: @cHao Emulation is possible and returning a TextNode is perfectly valid as a TextNode is a DomElement.

Comment: @Kevin: Sorry, a text node is not an element.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeType , and notice that ELEMENT_NODE and TEXT_NODE have two different types.

Comment: @cHao My apologies for incorrect terminology through the comments above. I was referring to it DomElement when I meant DomNode the entire time. In any case, even if DomElement is a requirement, emulation is easily performed to accommodate and this answer is incorrect in saying that it is not possible. That was the point of my comment and downvote.

Comment: @Kevin: Thing is, the answer is correct.  It explicitly says "you can not in effect target it directly" -- and here you are talking about emulation and returning text nodes as if they're elements, etc etc etc, thereby proving the point.  If the answer were wrong, then you wouldn't have to resort to all that.

Comment: @cHao If it could be targeted directly, then this question wouldn't exist yeah? If you read the op's question, he has asked how to _mimic_ the feature in jQuery. So, either this answer is wrong or playing captain obvious. In either case, it doesn't answer the question and my downvote reflects that.

Comment: @Kevin: It's *the* answer to the question.  The only other viable answer here doesn't even use jQuery, because jQuery can't do it, and even the non-jQuery version doesn't do any selecting.  It has to mangle the DOM in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use jQuery to pull out a specific letter because jQuery is a query language to pull out DOM elements.  You would need to split the text nodes and create new DOM elements (such as with a span) to actually target the specific letter.  However, it's not possible "without a bunch of spans."

Here's my attempt at something similar.  I should say that I don't really consider this production quality and it will totally have some bugs associated with it.  I hope it can instead give you some idea how to approach this problem using primarily string manipulation.

Again, this is a quick and dirty example to get you started.

```
function colorizeNthLetter(text, letter) {
    var words = text.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length > letter) {
            words[i] = words[i].substring(0, letter-1) + 
                       "<span class='color'>" + 
                       words[i].substring(letter-1, letter) + 
                       "</span>" + 
                       words[i].substring(letter);
        }
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sQ98n/

One likely bug is that splitting on a space to determine words is likely an incomplete way of thinking about word separation.  There's going to be more. :)

Comment: Another bug: once you've done this once, the count will be off.  You'd need to do a bit of work to figure out the correct count/position if you want to do this more than once in the same text node.

Comment: @cHao That's sort of true.  I wrote it under the assumption that it'd be used like my fiddle, passing in `$('#somelement').text()`, which would strip out any HTML markup, and thus you could run my bit over and over.  The only issue then becomes you cannot color more than one letter in each block, which yes is true!  Not really a bug though, just not what this was written to do.